# send mails from a php applciation using SMTP to internal exchange server

Tags: exchange, linux, php5, linux-networking

I have one Linux server which is connected to my local network and also internet in another network. I host some PHP applications on this server. All the PHP applications should able to send mails to all the mail server on the internet but one of my application have to send it to my exchange server in my local windows network.

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use your exchange server as a relay to send your email.  Unless you do the correct DNS and SMTP server configuration, your Linux server will likely look like a spam source.  This will cause you problems delivering email.

EDIT: You can setup a server on the Linux server using the Exchange server as a smarthost.